# What's wrong with these Ruby variables?

Tags: ruby, variables

I am trying to assign two variables and write a simple inline Ruby `if` statement within a method. I am getting an `unexpected tidentifier keyword_end`, indicating `^` at the end of the each variable names on all four lines;

```
1st_excl_checkbox = @browser.radio(:id => "opt2")
2nd_excl_checkbox = @browser.radio(:id => "opt1")
1st_excl_checkbox.set if 1st_excl_checkbox.exists?
2nd_excl_checkbox.set if 1st_excl_checkbox.exists?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have variables begin with a number.  Rename your variables to `first_excl_checkbox` and `second_excl_checkbox` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Even better: `checkboxes[0]` and `checkboxes[1]` in an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the name of the variables. In the ruby they can not start with a digit.

Comment: Friendly advice, change your name to something in latin letters. Most users here won't be able to read your name or type it to mention you.